# Permission problems after migrating from Apache to IIS

Tags: 6, migrations

After **migrating from Apache server to IIS** (7.5), I have some permission problems in Drupal: **modules don't seem to have the permissions to delete (unlink) or create files**, not even from/into ***"sites/default/files"*** folder.

What really interesting is, that **if I create my own `test.php` with a simple [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in it, it does create and unlink files without any error messages**.

---

BUT for example from AddThis module I got the following error message:

> unlink(`sites/default/files/addthis/addthis_widget.js`) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in
>   `C:\<mydrupalpath>\source\includes\file.inc` on line 481.

After that, I right clicked the mentioned file, Properties > Security tab > added Everyone with "Full control" rights. Not surprising, this way unlink was already successful.

BUT after that, I can see this it in the Drupal log:

> "The directory `sites/default/files/addthis` is not writable, because it
>   does not have the correct permissions set"

---

OK, **tried to set the right permissions with** [**`icacls`**](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) with granting "modify" and "write" permission to `sites/default/files` directory like this:

```
c:\<mydrupalpath>\source\sites\default\files /t /grant "IIS APPPOOL\MyDrupalAppPool":(OI)(CI)(M,W,RX)
```

OK, result is "*Successfully processed 228 files*".
Refreshing Drupal site in browser...
Hmm, didn't work, the **same error message** again (permission problems)...

I don't understand... if I query the rights with icacls on "***`files`***" OR `files\addthis` directory, it says my application pool does have "modify" rights:

```
IIS APPPOOL\MyDrupalAppPool:(OI)(CI)(M)
```

I do have permission problems with [Gallery module](http://drupal.org/project/gallery) too... :(

***What should I do not to have permission problems in "files" folder when modules try to delete from/write into it?***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php#install.windows.iis7.impersonation) I got the idea to run the following command on a console (*"Determining the account used as IIS anonymous identity"*):

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config "MyDrupalAppPool" ^ /section:anonymousAuthentication
```

The result was the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And then **running the following command seems to have solved the problem of writing to/deleting from the "`files`" directory**:

```
icacls c:\<mydrupalpath>\sites\default\files /t /grant IUSR:(OI)(CI)(M)
```

I don't know if it's secure enough... Please leave comments if you think there is any kind of problem with this approach. Thanks.